# How to animate a rectangle like a Progress Bar in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation, android-jetpack-compose

How to implement a progress bar like animation to the second rectangle, as well as control the animation such as **start** & **pause**

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ProgressBar(modifier: Modifier = Modifier.size(300.dp, 180.dp)) {
    Canvas(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(16.dp)) {
        val canvasWidth = size.width
        val canvasHeight = size.height
        val canvasSize = size

        val percentage = 0.2F

        drawRoundRect(
            color = Pink80,
            topLeft = Offset(x = 0F, y = 0F),
            size = Size(canvasSize.width, 55F),
            cornerRadius = CornerRadius(60F, 60F),
        )

        drawRoundRect(
            color = Purple40,
            topLeft = Offset(x = 0F, y = 0F),
            size = Size(canvasWidth * 0.2F , 55F),
            cornerRadius = CornerRadius(60F, 60F),
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Use this for reference https://fvilarino.medium.com/creating-a-segmented-progress-bar-in-jetpack-compose-40f312f8a568

Answer (score 2):

Here are two solutions. The first one uses Compose's own `LinearProgressIndicator`. The second one is a custom built one. It is very simple and has the advantage that you can easily customize it.

No need to use a canvas. When the progress bar reaches it's maximum, the code resets its value back to zero, but you can leave it set to 100% by not resetting the value. The LaunchedEffect is only being used to simulate updating the value. In a production app, you wouldn't use this but rather update the value with some other means that aligns with your code's business logic...

**LinearProgressIndicator:**

See: [LinearProgressIndicator](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary?hl=pt#LinearProgressIndicator(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color))

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        startActivity(intent)

        setContent {
            var enabled by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
            var progress by remember { mutableStateOf(0.1f) }
            val animatedProgress by animateFloatAsState(
                targetValue = progress,
            )

            LaunchedEffect(enabled) {
                while ((progress < 1) && enabled) {
                    progress += 0.005f
                    delay(10)
                }
            }

            if (progress >= 1f) {
                enabled = false
            }

            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(20.dp), horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                LinearProgressIndicator(progress = animatedProgress, modifier = Modifier.requiredHeight(20.dp))
                Spacer(Modifier.requiredHeight(30.dp))

                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        enabled = !enabled
                    }
                ) {
                    if (enabled) {
                        Text("Pause")
                    } else {
                        Text("Start")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Custom Progress Indicator:**

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        startActivity(intent)

        setContent {
            var enabled by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }.apply { this.value }
            var progressValue by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

            LaunchedEffect(enabled) {
                while ((progressValue < 100) && enabled) {
                    progressValue++
                    delay(10)
                }

                if (progressValue == 100) {
                    enabled = false
                    progressValue = 0
                }
            }

            Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(20.dp)) {
                ProgressBar(value = progressValue)

                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        enabled = !enabled
                    }
                ) {
                    if (enabled) {
                        Text("Pause")
                    } else {
                        Text("Start")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ProgressBar(
    value: Int
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .requiredHeight(20.dp)
            .border(width = 1.dp, color = Color.Black)
    ) {

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(value.toFloat() / 100f)
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .background(color = Color.Red)
        ) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/DogusTeknoloji/compose-progress

You can check this library as support animated and also step progress. The library base on canvas